# Remove the Matched string along with lines above and below the matched string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a set of strings in a log. 
I want to match a particular word in a line and want to remove the strings above and below it.

--> first, I want to match "sgd" and remove the strings which contains "sgd"

--> second, I want to match "current_line abc". If this matches, I dont want to print any "ins_bug" line.

Input:

```
  start_bug
  current_line  hdl/hjk/
  ins_bug {[sgd/hsjfk/123]}


  start_bug
  current_line  dsfd
  ins_bug {[hds/hdf/123]}



  start_bug
  current_line  ahd/ijk/
  ins_bug {[sgd/hsjfk/123]}

  start_bug
  current_line  abc
  ins_bug {[hk/hsjfk/123]}
  ins_bug {[hkcd/1235/465]}
  ins_bug {[hdkc/563/545]}

  start_bug
  current_line  hjkd
  ins_bug {[hds/hdf/123]}
  ins_bug {[dfv/1235/465]}
  ins_bug {[dsf/dfdg/dfdfd]}

  start_bug
  current_line  abc
  ins_bug {[dgds/hsgds/412]}
```

Output

```
  start_bug
  current_line  hdl/hjk/

  start_bug
  current_line  dsfd
  ins_bug {[hds/hdf/123]}

  start_bug
  current_line  ahd/ijk/

  start_bug
  current_line  hjkd
  ins_bug {[hds/hdf/123]}
  ins_bug {[dfv/1235/465]}
  ins_bug {[dsf/dfdg/dfdfd]}
```

Comment: Your description is very unclear. I don't see that either of those rules causes the block containing `current_line  ahd/ijk/` to be discarded

Comment: Hi, I will re-write it again about the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\bstart_bug\b(?:(?!\bstart_bug\b)[\s\S])*?\bsgd\b(?:(?!\bstart_bug\b)[\s\S])*
```

You can use this regex and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mG8kZ9/6

Comment: That's a hideous misuse of a regular expression. Anybody reading this code will take several minutes to understand what is going on here

Answer (score 2):

Your problem description is very unclear, but if this solution is correct then I think it's much simpler to read than a regex-based substitution. It sets `$/` to the empty string to enable paragraph input mode, and prints each paragraph unless it contains `sgd` or `current_line abc`

This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = shift;

open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};

local $/ = '';

while ( <$fh> ) {
    print unless /sgd/ or /current_line\s+abc/;
}
```

#### output

```
start_bug
current_line  dsfd
ins_bug {[hds/hdf/123]}

start_bug
current_line  hjkd
ins_bug {[hds/hdf/123]}
ins_bug {[dfv/1235/465]}
ins_bug {[dsf/dfdg/dfdfd]}
```

Comment: I think this is another good example of how just because you can regex, doesn't mean you should.